# Would prefab doors work for my angled shower space?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I've just moved into a new apartment with a trapezoidal shower space.

[image]

[image]

I don't think curtains would work well here for two reasons. First, the lip at the edge of the shower isn't very tall, and second, the shower is close enough to the wooden cabinet that I think it would get wet.

So we are interested in getting shower doors installed. Would it be possible to buy [prefabricated shower doors like this](https://www.wayfair.com/home-improvement/pdp/symphony-shower-doors-46-x-76-hinged-frameless-shower-door-fbth3123.html?piid=88980668) and hire someone to mount them? I'm concerned that the door hinge might not be suitable for mounting on an angled wall like the one we have. Or would we need to get everything made custom?

Comment: In answer to your question, "Yes", it's possible for you to buy them and have someone install them - any handyman worth his tool box should be able to hang them. If the door hinge can accommodate the angle you need to close, then they'll probably even work to keep the water in the shower. We can't tell if they'll close at the angle you need, though.

Comment: I sure hope there's a stud on the angled wall where the curb hits it.

Comment: Is this a rental? Do you have written permission to drill into the tiles? And if you’re allowed, have you considered a fixed panel beside the cabinet?

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on how it keeps itself in the "closed" position. If it is in the hinge on the angled wall keeping itself at 90° to the wall, then it is not suitable for your space.

If instead there is some mechanism where the doors meet and there is no bias in the hinges then it is perfectly suited for your space.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can buy prefabricated shower doors for your shower or not depends more on the exact size of the door you need and the what portion of it you need to to be stationary to have enough clearance for the sink.

Besides the model you linked to, with the hinges on the wall side, there are also similar style shower doors with the hinges between the two glass panels.
When going for hinges on the tile side, you need to ensure that the door can rest at the correct angle to your wall. When going for hinges on the side of the stationary pane, you need to add some buffer on the wall tide to prevent the glass from crashing into the tile when someone swings the door in the wrong direction.